# Add target to UIButton inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have `UIButton` inside my `CustomTableViewCell` and I also call `addTarget`:

```
let eyeButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(eyeButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    v.setImage(UIImage(named: "eyeOpen"), for: .normal)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

However this functions is not being called (also declared inside `CustomTableViewCell`):

```
@objc func eyeButtonTapped(){
    print("Hi")
}
```

There is a "tap-animation" when I click the `button` but nothing happens..

Anyone know why this happens and how I can fit it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring your button, `self` doesn't exist at that point.

Either add the target in your setup func, or change your declaration to a `lazy var`:

```
lazy var eyeButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(eyeButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    v.setImage(UIImage(named: "eyeOpen"), for: .normal)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Button Outlet Name  cellbuttonName or anyother   than write that code in tableviewdelegate cellForRowAtIndexPath

[self.cellbuttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];